# Prove that the total binary sequences of length n with no consecutive 1s is Fib(n+1) .

Tags: recursion, fibonacci-numbers, binary

I have seen multiple posts on how to prove this, but I don't understand why we need only `Fib(n-1)` and `Fib(n-2)` from the Fib series to prove it. Why do we only need Fib(n), Fib(n-1) and Fib(n-2)? How are these three elements in the series sufficient to tell total sequences of valid binary strings? Why can't we have something like `Fib(n) = Fib(n - 1) + Fib(n - 2) + C*Fib(n-3) +...`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving the number of $n$ length binary strings with no consecutive $1's$ $b_n$ is equal to $b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515784/proving-the-number-of-n-length-binary-strings-with-no-consecutive-1s-b-n)

Comment: @AnneBauval, I looked at it but couldn't figure out the answer to the doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Define $a_n$ as the number of $n$-sequences that ends with $1$ and $b_n$ the number of $n$-sequences that ends with $0$. It is easy to see that $b_{n+1}=a_n+b_n$ and $a_{n+1}=b_n$. From the second one we conclude that $b_{n+1}=b_n+b_{n-1}$ and that defining
$$c_n:=b_n+a_n=b_{n+1}$$
we conclude what we want.

Comment: A binary string of length (n+1) could end with 1 as well, so why didn't we show if for $a_{n + 1}$ in the final answer?