# Find the number of non-empty subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,8\}$ which do not contain two consecutive numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I obtained that for the set $A:=\{1,2\ldots,n\}$, the number of subsets $S$ of size $k$ such that no two elements of $S$ are consecutive numbers is $\binom{n-k+1}{k}$. Applying
$$\sum_{k=1}^{4} \binom{9-k}{k}$$ gives me $54$, however, the answer given is $34$. Is there any mistake I have made?

---

Derivation of $\binom{n-k+1}{k}$:
Define $X:=\{-1,0,1,\dots,n\}$. Note that no. of $k+1$ length subsets $S$ of $X$ with no two consecutive integers such that $-1 \in S$ forms a bijection with the number of $k$ length subsets of $A$ with no 2 consecutive numbers.

Write the elements of $X$ in a row and colour $-1$.
$$\color{red}{-1} \ \ 0 \ \ 1 \ \ \ldots\ \ n$$
We want to colour $k$ more numbers such that no two coloured numbers are consecutive. Define $g_i$ as the gap between the $i$th coloured number and the $i+1$th coloured number. For example, if we only colour $-1$ and $n$, $g_1 = n$. Thus, if we colour $k$ numbers other than $-1$, we observe that
$$\sum_{i=1}^k g_i \le n-k+1 \implies \left(\sum_{i=1}^k g_i\right) + t = n-k+1$$where $t$ is a non-negative integer. We note that each $g_i$ is greater than 0 (since we cannot colour consecutive integers), so we define $a_i = g_i-1$, so that $a_i$ are non-negative.
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i+1\right) + t = n-k+1 \implies \left(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i\right) + t = n-2k+1$$By stars and bars, the no. of solutions for this is
$$\binom{(n-2k+1)+(k+1)-1}{(k+1)-1} = \color{green}{\binom{n-k+1}{k}}$$

Comment: your answer is correct

Comment: How about also appending $n+1$ and $n+2$ to your row, where you always color $n+2$? Then $t$ can be replaced with $g_{k+1}$ and instead of an inequality you have a fixed sum.

Comment: @GunnarSveinsson I didn't think of that. But it will not change much, the upper bound for the sum of $g_i$ will increase by $1$, and that will be neutralized when we plug $g_{k+1} = a_{k+1}+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to rephrase this question is to ask about binary strings of length $n$ (in your case, $n=8$) for which there are no consecutive $1$'s. The bijection between such an approach and your question can be seen by viewing $0$ in slot $k$ as meaning "exclude $k$" and $1$ in slot $k$ as meaning "include $k$." If you want to specify nonempty, then you would just subtract one from the total (represented by the string of eight $0$'s).

With this view, you can now google and find the answer in various places, including MSE ([**example**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2515929/37122)).

If you are looking for just a hint, then looking at this from a **recursive** lens may be fruitful. In particular, how many strings of length $n = 1,2,3,4$ have no consecutive $1$'s? How does each case relate to the previous?

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant observation(+1)! That brings me to 54 again. Does that mean the given answer is wrong?

Comment: @Yes: You should end up with Fibonacci numbers, and, in particular, $55$ (so that if you exclude the empty set, then the answer is $54$ as you mention).

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is completely correct. There are 54 non consecutive subsets of the the first 8 natural numbers.

I can guess what mistake the book made.
One can prove that the total number of nonconsecutive subsets, including the empty subset,  of the first $n$ natural numbers is always a Fibonacci number, $F_{n+1}$. Note that 34 and 55 are both Fibonacci numbers; perhaps the book used $F_8$ instead of $F_{8+1}$, and also forgot to subtract one for the lack of empty set.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the correct answer is 54.

We denote the number of such subsets as $N(n, k)$ and consider two cases:

Case 1: The element $n$ is not in the subset.
In this case, we need to choose $k$ elements from the set ${1, 2, \dots, n-1}$ such that no two elements are consecutive. The number of ways to do this is $N(n-1, k)$.

Case 2: The element $n$ is in the subset.
In this case, we need to choose $k-1$ elements from the set ${1, 2, \dots, n-2}$ such that no two elements are consecutive. The number of ways to do this is $N(n-2, k-1)$.

Therefore, we can write the recurrence relation for $N(n, k)$ as
$$N(n, k) = N(n-1, k) + N(n-2, k-1)$$
Of course we could use this relation to verify your formula inductively, but to save time I wrote a little program to implement this recursive algorithm:

```
function f = re(n,k)
if k == 0
    f = 1;
elseif k>=n && n>1
    f = 0;
elseif n==2 && k == 1
    f = 2;
elseif n == 2 && k == 2
    f = 0;
elseif n == 1 && k == 1
    f = 1;
else
    f = re(n-1,k) + re(n-2,k-1);
end
end
```

The result is re(8,1)=8, re(8,2)=21, re(8,3)=20, re(8,4)=5.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach: Inclusion Exclusion

Much less elegant, but still viable.

See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.

Let $~S~$ denote the set of all non-empty subsets of $~\{1,2,\cdots,8\} \implies |S| = \displaystyle \left(2^8\right) - 1.$

For $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,7\},~$ let $~S_k~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ that contains both of the elements $~\{k,k+1\}.$

Then, the desired enumeration is

$$|S| - |S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots \cup S_7|.$$

Let $~T_0~$ denote $~|S| \implies T_0 = \displaystyle \left(2^8\right) - 1 = 255. \tag1 $

Let $~T_1~$ denote $~\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^7 |S_k|.~$ 
That is, $~T_1~$ represents the sum of $~\displaystyle \binom{7}{1}~$ numbers.

For $~r \in \{2,3,4,5,6,7\},~$ let $~T_r~$ denote 
$\displaystyle \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \leq 7} |S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap S_{i_r}|.$ 
That is, $~T_r~$ represents the sum of $~\displaystyle \binom{7}{r}~$ numbers.

Then, in accordance with Inclusion Exclusion Theory,

$$|S| - |S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots \cup S_7| = 
 \sum_{r = 0}^7 (-1)^r T_r. \tag2 $$

Therefore, the entire problem reduces to computing $~T_r ~: r \in \{1,2,\cdots,7\},~$ and then performing the computation on the RHS of (2) above.

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_1}$

For a set that is part of the collection represented by   $~S_1~$, the set must contain the specific elements $~1~$ and $~2.~$  Therefore, $~|S_1| = 2^6 = 64.~$

By symmetry, for each $~k \in \{2,3,4,5,6,7\},~$ you have that $~|S_k| = |S_1|.~$

Therefore,

$$~T_1 = 7 \times 64 = 448. \tag3 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_2}$

For a set that is part of the collection represented by   $~S_1\cap S_2~$, the set must contain the specific elements $~1, ~2,~$ and $~3.$  Therefore, $~|S_1 \cap S_2| = 2^5 = 32.~$

For a set that is part of the collection represented by   $~S_1\cap S_3~$, the set must contain the specific elements $~1, ~2, ~3,~$ and $~4.$  Therefore, $~|S_1 \cap S_3| = 2^4 = 16.~$

By symmetry, when examining the set intersections that will be used to compute the $~\displaystyle \binom{7}{2} = 21~$ terms in $~T_2,~$ exactly $~6~$ of them will have an enumeration of $~32~$ and the remaining $~(21 - 6) = 15~$ terms will have an enumeration of $~16.~$

Therefore,

$$~T_2 = (6 \times 32) + (15 \times 16) = 432. \tag4 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_3}$

For a set that is part of the collection represented by   $~S_1\cap S_2 \cap S_3~$, the set must contain the specific elements $~1, ~2, ~3,~$ and $~4.$  Therefore,
$~|S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3| = 2^4 = 16.~$

For a set that is part of the collection represented by   $~S_1\cap S_2 \cap S_4~$, the set must contain the specific elements $~1, ~2, ~3, ~4,~$ and $~5.$  Therefore,
$~|S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_4| = 2^3 = 8.~$

For a set that is part of the collection represented by   $~S_1 \cap S_3 \cap S_5~$, the set must contain the specific elements $~1, ~2, ~3, ~4, ~5~$ and $~6.$  Therefore, $~|S_1 \cap S_3 \cap S_5| = 2^2 = 4.~$

The computation of $~T_3~$ is complicated enough that I choose to complete this section by presenting the corresponding data lexicographically, in a table.

\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r |}
  \hline                       
  \text{Initial Sets} & \text{Added Set} & \text{Terms} & \text{Total} \\
  \hline                       
  1,2 & [3 : 4 : 5 : 6 : 7] & 16 + 8 + 8 + 8 + 8 & 48 \\ 
  1,3 & [4 : 5 : 6 : 7] & 8 + 4 + 4 + 4 & 20 \\
  1,4 & [5 : 6 : 7] & 8 + 4 + 4 & 16 \\
  1,5 & [6 : 7] & 8 + 4 & 12 \\
  1,6 & [7] & 8 & 8 \\
  \hline
  2,3 & [4 : 5 : 6 : 7] & 16 + 8 + 8 + 8 & 40 \\
  2,4 & [5 : 6 : 7] & 8 + 4 + 4 & 16 \\
  2,5 & [6 : 7] & 8 + 4 & 12 \\
  2,6 & [7] & 8 & 8 \\
  \hline
  3,4 & [5 : 6 : 7] & 16 + 8 + 8 & 32 \\
  3,5 & [6 : 7] & 8 + 4 & 12 \\
  3,6 & [7] & 8 & 8 \\
  \hline
  4,5 & [6 : 7] & 16 + 8 & 24 \\
  4,6 & [7] & 8 & 8 \\
  \hline
  5,6 & [7] & 16 & 16 \\
  \hline 
  & & & \color{red}{280} \\
  \hline  
\end{array}
Therefore,

$$~T_3 = 280. \tag5 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Subsequent} ~T_r~ \text{Computations}}$

Initially, I considered that (for example) there is a 1-1 correspondence between the $~\displaystyle \binom{7}{3} = 35~$ set intersections represented in the enumeration of $~T_3~$ and the $~\displaystyle \binom{7}{4} = 35~$ set intersections represented in the enumeration of $~T_4.$

However, consider the specific $~T_3~$ terms represented by
$~|S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3|,~$ and $~|S_2 \cap S_3 \cap S_4|.~$  These two terms have the same enumeration.

Now consider the corresponding $~T_4~$ terms represented by
$~|S_4 \cap S_5 \cap S_6 \cap S_7|~$ and $~|S_1 \cap S_5 \cap S_6 \cap S_7|.~$ These two terms do **not** have the same enumeration.  Therefore, I abandoned this approach.

Instead, for the computations of $~T_4, T_5,~$ and $~T_6,~$ I also choose to present the corresponding data lexicographically, in a table.

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_4}$

\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r |}
  \hline                       
  \text{Initial Sets} & \text{Added Set} & \text{Terms} & \text{Total} \\
  \hline                       
  1,2,3 & [4 : 5 : 6 : 7] & 8 + 4 + 4 + 4 & 20 \\ 
  1,2,4 & [5 : 6 : 7] & 4 + 2 + 2 & 8 \\
  1,2,5 & [6 : 7] & 4 + 2 & 6 \\
  1,2,6 & [7] & 4 & 4 \\
  \hline 
  1,3,4 & [5 : 6 : 7] & 4 + 2 + 2 & 8 \\ 
  1,3,5 & [6 : 7] & 2 + 1 & 3 \\
  1,3,6 & [7] & 2 & 2 \\
  \hline 
  1,4,5 & [6 : 7] & 4 + 2 & 6 \\ 
  1,4,6 & [7] & 2 & 2 \\
  \hline 
  1,5,6 & [7] & 4 & 4 \\
  \hline
  2,3,4 & [5 : 6 : 7] & 8 + 4 + 4 & 16 \\ 
  2,3,5 & [6 : 7] & 4 + 2 & 6 \\
  2,3,6 & [7] & 4 & 4 \\
  \hline  
  2,4,5 & [6 : 7] & 4 + 2 & 6 \\ 
  2,4,6 & [7] & 2 & 2 \\
  \hline  
  2,5,6 & [7] & 4 & 4 \\
  \hline  
  3,4,5 & [6 : 7] & 8 + 4 & 12 \\ 
  3,4,6 & [7] & 4 & 4 \\
  \hline
  3,5,6 & [7] & 4 & 4 \\
  \hline
  4,5,6 & [7] & 8 & 8 \\
  \hline  
  & & & \color{red}{129} \\
  \hline  
\end{array}
Therefore,

$$~T_4 = 129. \tag6 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_5}$

\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r |}
  \hline                       
  \text{Initial Sets} & \text{Added Set} & \text{Terms} & \text{Total} \\
  \hline                       
  1,2,3,4 & [5 : 6 : 7] & 4 + 2 + 2 & 8 \\ 
  1,2,3,5 & [6 : 7] & 2 + 1 & 3 \\
  1,2,3,6 & [7] & 2 & 2 \\
  \hline 
  1,2,4,5 & [6 : 7] & 2 + 1 & 3 \\ 
  1,2,4,6 & [7] & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline
  1,2,5,6 & [7] & 2 & 2 \\
  \hline 
  1,3,4,5 & [6 : 7] & 2 + 1 & 3 \\ 
  1,3,4,6 & [7] & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline 
  1,3,5,6 & [7] & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline
  1,4,5,6 & [7] & 2 & 2 \\
  \hline
  2,3,4,5 & [6 : 7] & 4 + 2 & 6 \\ 
  2,3,4,6 & [7] & 2 & 2 \\
  \hline
  2,3,5,6 & [7] & 2 & 2 \\
  \hline  
  2,4,5,6 & [7] & 2 & 2 \\ 
  \hline
  3,4,5,6 & [7] & 4 & 4 \\
  \hline  
  & & & \color{red}{42} \\
  \hline  
\end{array}
Therefore,

$$~T_5 = 42. \tag7 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~T_6}$

\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r |}
  \hline                       
  \text{Initial Sets} & \text{Added Set} & \text{Terms} & \text{Total} \\
  \hline                       
  1,2,3,4,5 & [6 : 7] & 2 + 1 & 3 \\ 
  1,2,3,4,6 & [7] & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline
  1,2,3,5,6 & [7] & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline 
  1,2,4,5,6 & [7] & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline 
  1,3,4,5,6 & [7] & 1 & 1 \\
  \hline 
  2,3,4,5,6 & [7] & 2 & 2 \\
  \hline 
  & & & \color{red}{9} \\
  \hline  
\end{array}
Therefore,

$$~T_6 = 9. \tag8 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of}}$

$T_7~$ represents $|S_1 \cap S_2 \cap \cdots \cap S_7|$ which implies that the subset must have each of the elements in $~\{1,2,3,\cdots,8\}.$

Therefore,

$$~T_7 = 1. \tag9 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

$$T_0 - T_1 + T_2 - T_3 + T_4 - T_5 + T_6 - T_7 = \\
(T_0 + T_2 + T_4 + T_6) - (T_1 + T_3 + T_5 + T_7) = \\
(255 + 432 + 129 + 9) - (448 + 280 + 42 + 1) = 54.$$